LaTeX document header
I'm trying to reproduce this template for a physics lesson sheet and I can't put the header which contains : "Prof :  ; Vecteurs et Translation ; Année"

This is what I tried :
\documentclass[french,10pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Les Vecteurs}
    
\subsection{Caractéristiques d'un vecteur}
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
    
    $\overrightarrow{AB}$ \text{ est un vecteur : } 
    
    
    $
    \begin{cases}
        \star ~ \textbf{Direction : } \text{ droite } (AB) \\
        \star ~ \textbf{Sens : } \text{ sens de la droite } (AB) \text{ de } A \text{ vers } B \\
        \star ~ \textbf{Norme (module) : } \text{ longueur } AB
    \end{cases}
    $
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{3cm}
    \begin{center}
        \definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,>=stealth]
            %   \clip(-2,-1) rectangle (4,3);
            \draw [->,line width=1.5pt] (0,0) -- (3,2);
            \draw[color=red] (-1.4,0.6) node[anchor=north west,scale=0.6] {Origine};
            \draw[color=blue] (0.9,2.5) node[anchor=north west,scale=0.6] {Extrémité};
            \begin{scriptsize}
                \draw [fill=red] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
                \draw [fill=blue] (3,2) circle (1.5pt);
                \draw[color=blue] (3.2,2.3) node {$B$};
                \draw[color=red] (0,-0.25) node {$A$};
            \end{scriptsize}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}

This is the result :

The page numbering is also not displayed correctly.

Off topic. Take a look at the package unicode-math with option math-style=french (with a compilation lualatex)

You can use fancyhdr to configure the headings and footer and the package geometry to correctly setup your footer and header distances
\documentclass[french,10pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm,footskip=3pt,headsep=12pt,headheight=0.7cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.2pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{Prof:}
    \fancyhead[C]{Vecteurs et Translation}
    \fancyhead[R]{Année}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \begin{multicols*}{2}
        \section{Les Vecteurs}
        
        \subsection{Caractéristiques d'un vecteur}
        \begin{minipage}{7cm}
            
            $\overrightarrow{AB}$ \text{ est un vecteur : } 
            
            
            $
            \begin{cases}
                \star ~ \textbf{Direction : } \text{ droite } (AB) \\
                \star ~ \textbf{Sens : } \text{ sens de la droite } (AB) \text{ de } A \text{ vers } B \\
                \star ~ \textbf{Norme (module) : } \text{ longueur } AB
            \end{cases}
            $
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{3cm}
            \begin{center}
                \definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,>=stealth]
                    %   \clip(-2,-1) rectangle (4,3);
                    \draw [->,line width=1.5pt] (0,0) -- (3,2);
                    \draw[color=red] (-1.4,0.6) node[anchor=north west,scale=0.6] {Origine};
                    \draw[color=blue] (0.9,2.5) node[anchor=north west,scale=0.6] {Extrémité};
                    \begin{scriptsize}
                        \draw [fill=red] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
                        \draw [fill=blue] (3,2) circle (1.5pt);
                        \draw[color=blue] (3.2,2.3) node {$B$};
                        \draw[color=red] (0,-0.25) node {$A$};
                    \end{scriptsize}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{multicols*}
\end{document}



Probably the packages fancyhdr and tcolorbox are your friends and probably you are interested in TikZ's positioning library:
\documentclass[french,10pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[x11names, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newbox\scratchboxA
\newbox\scratchboxB
\setbox\scratchboxA\hbox{Prof Vecteurs et Translation Année}%
\setbox\scratchboxB\hbox{0123456789}%
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, 
            headheight=.5\dimexpr(1cm+\ht\scratchboxA+\dp\scratchboxA+\headrulewidth+\headruleskip)\relax, 
            headsep=.5\dimexpr(1cm-\ht\scratchboxA-\dp\scratchboxA-\headrulewidth-\headruleskip)\relax, 
            footskip=.5\dimexpr(1cm+\ht\scratchboxB+\dp\scratchboxB)\relax]{geometry}
%In case of footrules with \footskip take  \footrulewidth / \footruleskip into account.
%---------------------------
\fancyhead[L]{Prof}
\fancyhead[C]{Vecteurs et Translation}
\fancyhead[R]{Année}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L,R]{}
% if twoside:
% \fancyhead[EL, OL]{Prof}
% \fancyhead[EC, OC]{Vecteurs et Translation}
% \fancyhead[ER, OR]{Année}
% \fancyfoot[EC, OC]{\thepage}
% \fancyfoot[EL, ER, OL, OR]{}
%---------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newlength\scratchlength

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\columnsep=1cm
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\section{Les Vecteurs}
\subsection{Caractéristiques d'un vecteur}
\noindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
  width=\linewidth, 
  colback=white, 
  colframe=red,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-.5\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox+2\fboxsep\relax},
  coltitle=FireBrick,
  boxed title style={colback=red!5!white, colframe=red!5!white},
  title=Définition 1,
]
\begin{minipage}[c]{\dimexpr(\tcbtextwidth -2.9cm)\relax}%
    % The \hrules make aligning minipages [t] or [b] or [c] easier.
    \hrule height 0pt
    $\overrightarrow{AB}$  est un vecteur : %
    $
    \begin{cases}
        \star ~ \textbf{Direction : } \text{ droite } (AB) \\
        \star ~ \textbf{Sens : } \vtop{\hbox{$\text{sens de la droite }(AB)\text{ de }A$\strut}\hbox{$\text{vers } B$\strut}}\\
        \star ~ \textbf{Norme (module) : } \text{ longueur } AB
    \end{cases}
    $%
    \hrule height 0pt
\end{minipage}%%%% no breapoint between minipages!
\begin{minipage}[c]{2.9cm}%
    \hrule height 0pt
    \begin{flushright}%
        \scratchlength=-2\dimexpr\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}\relax
        \edef\myleftshift{\the\numexpr\scratchlength\relax sp}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,>=stealth, node distance=0 and 0]
            % Thickness of lines with TikZ is:
            % 
            % /tikz/ultra thin   -   Sets the line width to 0.1pt = 0.03514598 mm.
            % /tikz/very thin    -   Sets the line width to 0.2pt = 0.07029196 mm.
            % /tikz/thin         -   Sets the line width to 0.4pt = 0.14058392 mm.
            % /tikz/semithick    -   Sets the line width to 0.6pt = 0.21087588 mm.
            % /tikz/thick        -   Sets the line width to 0.8pt = 0.28116784 mm.
            % /tikz/very thick   -   Sets the line width to 1.2pt = 0.42175176 mm.
            % /tikz/ultra thick  -   Sets the line width to 1.6pt = 0.56233568 mm.
            \draw [thin, fill=red] (0,0) node[anchor=north, red] (A) {$A$} circle (3.2pt);
            \draw [thin, fill=blue] (2.5,1.75) node[anchor=south, blue] (B) {$B$} circle (3.2pt);
            \draw [->,ultra thick] (A.north) -- (B.south);
            \node[left=\myleftshift of A.south west, anchor=south east, red] {\footnotesize Origine\! \null};
            \node[left=\myleftshift of B.north west, anchor=north east, blue] {\footnotesize Extrémité\! \null};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{flushright}%
    \unskip
    \hrule height 0pt
\end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}


